# How can I calculate percentage between two queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to generate a result or create a view that is based on calculating the percentage of one query/another query.

These are the queries:

Query1:

```
SELECT
count(distinct email), Utility
from elec_cust
where email != 'NULL' and MAILLIST = '1'
GROUP BY Utility
ORDER BY count(distinct email)
```

And 
Query2:

```
SELECT
count(distinct email), Utility
from elec_cust
where email != 'NULL' and MAILLIST = '0'
GROUP BY Utility
ORDER BY count(distinct email)
```

I'm looking to generate the result of Query2/Query1 as a percentage:

Utility | Percentage

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MAILLIST = '1' THEN email END) as Query_1_result,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MAILLIST = '0' THEN email END) as Query_2_result,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MAILLIST = '1' THEN email END)/COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MAILLIST = '0' THEN email END)*100 AS Perc_Col ,
       Utility
from elec_cust
where email != 'NULL' 
GROUP BY Utility
```

MySQL treats Boolean expressions like `1` for true, and `0` for false. So this will sum the `MAILLIST = '1'` and will divide it with `MAILLIST = '0'`

You can remove the first two columns, I've added them for your comfort.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it needs one additional edit - the counts are not taking into account the DISTINCT qualifier; since there is duplication of emails, I need to calculate based only on DISTINCT values for email. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @sagi - that was it!